# Error in constructor receiving two parameters by value

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Sometimes I find very useful, for simplicity and efficiency, using this type of iterator:

```
// Chunk 1
    template <class Itor1, class Itor2 = Itor1>
class Pair_Iterator
{
  Itor1 it1;
  Itor2 it2;

public:

  Pair_Iterator(Itor1 i1, Itor2 i2) : it1(i1), it2(i2) {}

  bool has_curr() const { return it1.has_curr() and it2.has_curr(); }

  auto get_curr() const
  {
    return std::make_pair(it1.get_curr(), it2.get_curr());
  }

  void next()
  {
    it1.next();
    it2.next();
  }
};
```

The idea is to traverse simultaneously two containers, which may be of different types, through its iterators.

Now, for a reason I do not manage not understand, the next test does not compile:

```
// previous chunk could be included here
struct It1
{
  It1() {}
  bool has_curr() const { return true; }
  int get_curr() const { return 1; }
  void next() {}
};

int main()
{
  for (Pair_Iterator<It1> it(It1(), It1()); it.has_curr(); it.next())
    ;
}
```

clang compiler (version 3.8) says:

```
error: member reference base type 'Pair_Iterator<It1> (It1 (*)(), It1 (*)())'
      is not a structure or union
  for (Pair_Iterator<It1> it(It1(), It1()); it.has_curr(); it.next())
                                            ~~^~~~~~~~~
it.C:57:62: error: member reference base type 'Pair_Iterator<It1> (It1 (*)(), It1 (*)())'
      is not a structure or union
  for (Pair_Iterator<It1> it(It1(), It1()); it.has_curr(); it.next())
                                                       ~~^~~~~
```

And gnu compiler (version 5.3) says:

```
error: request for member ‘has_curr’ in ‘it’, which is of non-class type ‘Pair_Iterator<It1>(It1 (*)(), It1 (*)())’
   for (Pair_Iterator<It1> it(It1(), It1()); it.has_curr(); it.next())
                                                ^
it.C:57:63: error: request for member ‘next’ in ‘it’, which is of non-class type ‘Pair_Iterator<It1>(It1 (*)(), It1 (*)())’
   for (Pair_Iterator<It1> it(It1(), It1()); it.has_curr(); it.next())
```

However, if I change the `Pair_Iterator` instantiation by:

```
It1 it1;
for (Pair_Iterator<It1> it(it1, It1()); it.has_curr(); it.next())
```

then everything compiles perfectly.

So my question would be:

1. Why the first instantiation is invalid (I presume that because two compilers reject it)
2. Is there any way to write `Pair_Iterator` so that the instantiation of interest passes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have joined the millions of people around the world struggling with [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

```
Pair_Iterator<It1> it(It1(), It1())
```

This is interpreted as a function taking two pointers to function returning `It1` that then returns a `Pair_Iterator<It1>`. Use uniform initialization syntax to resolve it, or wrap them in extra parenthesis.

```
Pair_Iterator<It1> it{It1(), It1()}
```

It succeeds in the second case because `It()` is a type followed by parenthesis, so it's possible it could be a function type. However, the name of a variable forces the compiler to realize it is instantiating a new variable, not declaring a function.

---

In general, when an expression looks like `type name(type(), type())`, it should be replaced with:

```
type name{type(), type()}
//or
type name = type(type(), type())
//or
type name((type()), (type()))
```

The number of `type()` parameters doesn't matter; `type name(type())` or `type name(type(), type(), type())` suffer from the same problem.

Comment: the oldschool way would be to write `Pair_Iterator<It1> it = Pair_Iterator<It1>(It1(),It1());`, just in case it is about pre c++11

Comment: @tobi303 Question is tagged C++14.